# R: removing certain elements in a vector

Tags: r

I have a vector:

```
L <- c("ada1","ada2","efg1","efg7","ia8","ib9","ia4","ag7","ia11")
L
```

However I need to remove those elements that start with ia

I tried :

```
L[-grep("\\ia")]
```

But this gives me an error and does not give me the desired result:

```
c("ada1","ada2","efg1","efg7","ib9","ag7")
```

I would be grateful for your help in pointing out the errors I have made above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to pass `L` to `grep()`:

```
L[-grep("^ia",L)]
[1] "ada1" "ada2" "efg1" "efg7" "ib9"  "ag7"
```

Comment: To avoid typing `L` twice, the OP can use `grep("^ia",L,value=TRUE,invert=TRUE)`.

Comment: @Frank but value has an L in it o.0